# MODI in MS Office 2016

Tags: microsoft-office, ocr, microsoft-office-2016

I have heard about scanned document OCR feature in MS Office.

I was trying to copy scanned document image to clipboard and paste it as text in notepad as text, but this doesn't work.

I have Office 2016 running on Win 8.1. How to enable MODI and use it ?

Comment: where did you heard it? Did you copied from which program to where?

Answer (score 2):

You can install Modi via SharePoint 2007. MODI was removed from office 2010 onward I believe.

Instructions at http://www.myloginvault.co.uk/microsoft-office-document-imaging/

Hope that helps

Edit as per comment. Download SharePoint designer 2007 from the Microsoft's website (its free - about 300Mb). Run the installer and under office tools select MODI and run all from computer. Install and then search for MODI on your PC.

Comment: Link-only answers are not very useful. Links to external resources are encouraged, but in general, it’s best for answers to be as self-contained as possible as the URL may change or go permanently offline.I would suggest that you [edit] the answer to include the most important/relevant information from the linked article.

Comment: It's the Sharepoint Designer 2007 you want to download, not the full Sharepoint install: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=21581

Answer (score 0):

Use the free Microsoft Onenote Windows desktop application: 
https://www.onenote.com/download/win32/x86/en-US

You can paste an image into a onenote page, then right click the image and "Copy Text from Picture".
The OCR text will be placed on the clipboard.